# rails4 + Pundit model instance not defined in policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I defines a Pundit policy "CompanyPolicy" as stated in the documentation , the scopez gives the expected results ( on :index ) but I get an exception trying to use the company model instance :

```
 *** NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `company' for #<CompanyPolicy:
```

here is the CompanyPolicy.rb

```
  class CompanyPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

      class Scope
        attr_reader :user, :scope

        def initialize(user, scope)
          @user = user
          @scope = scope
        end

        def resolve
          if user.system_admin?
            scope.all
          else
            Company.none
          end
        end
      end

      def new?
        user.system_admin? ? true : false
      end

      def edit?
        user.system_admin? ? true : false
      end

      def show?
        user.system_admin? ? true : false
      end

      def destroy?
        internal_name = Rails.application.secrets.internal_company_short_name
        # do not destroy the internal company record 
        user.system_admin? && (company[:short_name] !=  internal_name ) ? true : false
      end
  end
```

and I check it from the Company controller

```
 def destroy
   authorize @company
   #@company.destroy
   ....
 end
```

why  (company[:short_name]  is wrong ?

If I look into the Pundit doc , the example with the PostPolicy , scope and post.published is similar ...

```
        class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
          class Scope
            attr_reader :user, :scope

            def initialize(user, scope)
              @user = user
              @scope = scope
            end

            def resolve
              if user.admin?
                scope.all
              else
                scope.where(:published => true)
              end
            end
          end

          def update?
            user.admin? or not post.published?
          end
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into [documentation](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#policies):

> Pundit makes the following assumptions about this class:
>
> - The class has the same name as some kind of model class, only    suffixed with the word "Policy".
> - The first argument is a user. In    your controller, Pundit will call the current_user method to retrieve    what to send into this
>     argument
> - The second argument is some kind of    model object, whose authorization you want to check. This does not    need to be an
>     ActiveRecord or even an ActiveModel object, it can be    anything
>     really.
> - The class implements some kind of query method, in    this case update?. Usually, this will map to the name of a particular
>     controller action.
>
> That's it really.
>
> Usually you'll want to inherit from the application policy created by
>   the generator, or set up your own base class to inherit from:
>
> ```
> class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
>   def update?
>     user.admin? or not record.published?
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> **In the generated ApplicationPolicy, the model object is called `record`**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying it ...

In the generated ApplicationPolicy, the model object is called record

Comment: Andre or @erwin is there a way to access the 'record' object in the scope class?

Answer (score 0):

just discovered that one should use @record rather than company
( read the a question related to scopes  :  [Implementing scopes in Pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616608/implementing-scopes-in-pundit) )

but I don't understand why the Pundit doc does not mention it , and still use a model instance like 'post' for PostPolicy ... 
can someone enlighten us ?